# agregar espacio entre cada <th></th> <th></th>

Tags: php, html

**No se como hacer espacios ademas del &nbsp ;**

```
<?php
    echo"<th><br>Datos Actuales</th>/*Aqui quiero el espacio*/<th><br>Datos Nuevos</th></tr><tr>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías agregar un margen a la izquierda con CSS a todas las etiquetas `th` que van después de otra eqtiqueta `th`:

```
<style>
th + th {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: tks, me funciona para otra parte del codigo en la misma pagina

Answer (score 0):

Despues de mucho rato pensar e investigar descubri que al algregar colspan=2 a la linea anterior del th para si darle el espaciado

```
echo"<th colspan=2><br>Datos Actuales</th>";
echo"<th><br>Datos Nuevos</th>";
```